# android animatorset memory management, freeing up memory from imageview

Tags: android, android-animation, android-memory

I have a repeating AnimatorSet that uses a sequence of full frame images on several different activities.  I'm getting an out of memory exception as it seems that the imageviews are taking up too much memory.

Originally the activities in the background still had their animations running in a loop taking up memory.  I tried remedying by creating and ending animations on pause/resume so that memory from animations in the non-foreground views are reclaimed but I think I need to do more to clear out the imageviews from memory as well.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_face_o_matic_start);
        getActionBar().hide();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    createAnimations();
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.mAnimatorSet.removeAllListeners();
    this.mAnimatorSet.end();
            //TODO: clear and free up the memory from the image views somehow
            // this is the part I need help with I think

}

protected ObjectAnimator getGlowAnimation(View v, int duration){
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
    animation.setDuration(duration);
    animation.setRepeatCount(1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    return animation;
}

public void createAnimations(){

    //TODO: destroy these imageviews to reclaim memory on pause
            // originally had them in on create but the imageviews continued to
            // take up memory when the activity went into the background
    /*start animations */

    final ImageView bg1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg_face_o_matic_1);
    final ImageView bg2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg_face_o_matic_2);
    final ImageView bg3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg_face_o_matic_3);
    final ImageView bg4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg_face_o_matic_4);
    final ImageView bg5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg_face_o_matic_5);
    final ImageView bg6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bg_face_o_matic_6);

    ObjectAnimator anim1 = getGlowAnimation(bg1, 400);
    ObjectAnimator anim2 = getGlowAnimation(bg2, 400);      
    ObjectAnimator anim3 = getGlowAnimation(bg3, 400);
    ObjectAnimator anim4 = getGlowAnimation(bg4, 400);
    ObjectAnimator anim5 = getGlowAnimation(bg5, 400);
    ObjectAnimator anim6 = getGlowAnimation(bg6, 400);

    List<Animator> animations = new ArrayList<Animator>(Arrays.asList(anim1, anim2, anim3, anim4, anim5, anim6));
    mAnimatorSet.playSequentially(animations);
            //loop the animator set
    mAnimatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            mAnimatorSet.start();

        }

    });

    mAnimatorSet.start();
    /*end animations */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everytime your application enters this `Activity` it calls your `onResume()` method, in which it calls `createAnimations()`, hence it is continuously creating lots of images and other stuff. You should declare some stuff outside of this method, declare them on class-level and init them in `onCreate()` so it will be much more efficient. I reduced your `createAnimations()` a bit. And just call this method once in your `onCreate()` after you initialize its necessary dependency variables and in your `onResume()` just call `mAnimatorSet.playSequentially(animations);`

```
public void createAnimations(){


    mAnimatorSet.playSequentially(animations);
            //loop the animator set
    mAnimatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter(){

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            mAnimatorSet.start();

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: what should I do to free up memory, originally I had the imageviews and what not in the oncreate but it never freed up the memory on pause, I moved the initialization of the imageviews to on resume thinking that I would destory the imageviews on pause.. but I didn't progress to the destroying images just yet so that's half completed.. what should I do to free up images from the imageviews and object animators on pause?

Comment: there is a recycle() method for images, but doing allocate/deallocate frequently will make things worse, i suggested to init them in onCreate because you use them all the time without change so initting them once will work out, dont init them onResume() as it will be called multiple time, so it will perform worse rather than benefit

Comment: The activity in our case only resumes only once per user session (it's a specific use case) and the performance has been good enough for us thus far, but the memory issue was the critical issue.  Will the recycle method deallocate the images and free up memory?  if so, how to reallocate on resume?

Comment: recycle() will free-up the memory. but why you want to reallocate in onResume(), didn't you say it will show up only once?

Comment: I meant that it only resumes once, so it shows up on create and only one of the activities has as a resume event after it returns from a facebook login.

Comment: ah then, dont use recycle() as it will assume you dont need to draw that bitmap again, so it will give an error "Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap". and btw do your images has a big resoulution? for a detailed guide about bitmap memory take a look at this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: The images are full-frame, meaning they take up the entire android galaxy background, full size

Comment: ok here is the deal, declare a boolean it will indicate whether you are done with showing that image, and in your onResume() compare this, if that boolean still indicates you should show image, then show image, otherwise recycle() the image as you never need it anymore,